# How to upload large scanned files to mongodb - about 1 gigabyte

Tags: mongodb, upload, large-files

I am scanning multiple large files for archiving, files size is too large about 500 megabytes to 2 gigabyte.

What is the best way to store these files to mongodb database.
Should I save files temporary to client device, or should I first upload these files to folder on the server, or save it directly to mongodb.

How to make sure all files are saved without loosing any part?

I am trying to find the best soultion to upload large files

Comment: [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/)?

Comment: Storing giant images in MongoDB (indeed, almost any DB) adds no value.   No indexing or querying opportunities.   I would store them on cheap media and store the locations plus metadata in MongoDB.   That said, see GridFS comment above.